# Почему c++ неосновной язык для android?

Tags: android, c++

Программируя на с++ под андроид нужно писать код конкретно для каждого процессора(snapgragon, exynos, atom)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код должен быть скомпилирован конкретно под каждую архитектуру - arm, x86, mips, а не модель процессора.

В том числе и поэтому Андроид на виртуальной машине, что поддерживает несколько архитектур без необходимости компиляции под каждую из них. Java-код универсален при компиляции, а С++ код архитектурно-зависим.

С другой стороны не понятно, какие претензии у вас к операционной системе Android. На любой платформе С++ код зависим от архитектуры на клиентской машине.

Comment: Получается если писать с помощью ndk то код будет либо для arm, либо для х86?

Comment: @EldarEldar Код будет на С++ - это язык высокого уровня, а из исходников на С++ вы можете скомпилировать исполняемый файл и под arm и под x86. Если в пакете будет два скомпилированных модуля (под arm и под x86), то ваш код будет работать на архитектуре arm и на архитектуре x86. По сборке под разные архитектуры читайте [офф.документацию](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html?hl=ru). И вообще, если взялись, сделайте для начала усилие хотя бы официальное руководство по NDK изучить. Там **все** написано, а с конкретными проблемами уже сюда обращайтесь.